# How to change input text to select box and populate it?

Tags: jquery

I need to get options from a select, change another text input to select, and populate that select with data from first select.

For the moment I have this code,to get the code from fist dropdown:

```
var optionValues = [];
jQuery('#rofile_user option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

I don't know how to change the input text to select box, and populate the select. If you wonder why I need to change/need the text input, is becouse I use a CMS, and that text box is there for a reason

Comment: `jQuery('#rofile_user option').each(function() {
                optionValues.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });` will select exactly **one** DOM element, then run exactly **once** (assuming it finds an element).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two elements on the page, one visible and one hidden. When you want to "change" the text input to a select, simply hide one and show the other. jQuery does not allow you to change the type of an input.

Answer (score 0):

For copying the options over from one select to another, you can do the following:

```
    $('#select2').html($('select1').html());
```

That should copy all of the options over for you.

As for "changing" the input, it wouldn't be too tough to create a new select in the same spot as the input, then remove the input.  Would that approach work?

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<select id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>

<input id="input"/>
```

**js**

```
$('#input').after($('#select').clone().attr('id','select2')).remove();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydnsrdc0/1/)**